# Navigate to pinned application with number > 10 in windows

Tags: windows, alt-tab, keyboard-navigation

I can navigate to the first ten pinned applications in application bar with keyboard:

- <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>
- <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>
- ...
- <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

It is a very convinient way to instant navigation. However, I have a set of more than 10 required applcations. There are some composite ways to navigate applications with higher order I do not like for it sluggishness. Is there some plugin application to Windows or something for instant navigate to the pinned applications with order greater than 10 (I guess the 20 applications going to be enough)

Answer (score 0):

There is some help from backword navigation: 
<kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>Left</kbd>`x N`

The first keyboard shortcut switch focus to appbar. And with left/right arrows one can navigate trough application icons.